# A monomorphism from a ring to a direct sum

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a ring with a family of ideals $A_i$'s ($i\in I)$. We could consider a well-defined $R$-monomorphism from $R/∩A_i$ to the direct product of $R/A_i$'s sending $r+∩A_i$ to the tuple $(r+A_i)_{i\in I}$. But, how could we define an $R$-monomorphism from $R/∩A_i$ to the direct sum of $R/A_i$'s? Of course, when $I$ is finite, this map is the same as that above. Thanks for any cooperation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a general collection of ideals $\{A_i\}$, no.

The problem is that the tuple $(r+A_i)_{i\in I}$ is only a member of $\oplus_{i\in I} R/A_i$ when all but finitely many of the elements are zero.

In other words, we can define such a map exactly when our collection of ideals has the following property: for all $r\in R$, $r\in A_i$ for all but finitely many $A_i$.

But this last property is always very boring when $R$ is a ring with $1$, because $1$ does not lie in any ideal except $R$ itself.  So this map is defined when all but finitely many of the ideals are equal to $R$—if the ideals are distinct, this means that $I$ is already finite.

---

Here is an example of a situation where we cannot possibly hope to get a monomorphism into the direct sum.

Let $R = \mathbb{C}[X]$, and let $I = \{(X-c) \mid c\in \mathbb{C}\}$.  Importantly, we have $R/(X-c)\cong \mathbb{C}$ via the epimorphism $f(X)\mapsto f(c)$.

We have $\bigcap_c (X-c) = 0$, and a very nice monomorphism $R\to \prod_c R/(X-c)$, namely $f(X) \mapsto (f(c))_c$.  In other words, polynomials are determined by their values.

But $S = \oplus_c R/(x-c)$ is a different story.  It's a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{C}$, and this means that any nonzero element of $S$ generates a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra that is finite-dimensional as a vector space.  Since $X\in R$ clearly generates an algebra that is infinite-dimensional as a vector space, there is nowhere for it to be sent by a monomorphism $R\to S$.

(if you would rather work with rings instead of $\mathbb{C}$-algebras, the same example works with $R=\mathbb{Z}[X]$—just replace "dimension" with "rank")

Comment: Thanks for answering. Your assertions are true, however, I did not mean to insist on the very map introduced when searching for a monomorphism to the direct sum!

Comment: @karparvar If you're not insisting on the map, then it's hard to say very much.  There are lots of rings, and lots of sets of ideals you can write down, and lots of maps.  But none of these maps are going to be as useful and natural as the one you described.  For example, if every element of $r$ is determined by some sub-collection of $I$, I can take your map for those ideals, and do something wacky with all the rest.  It's still a monomorphism, of course, but it's not terribly interesting.  Anyway, I've just added an example of why there can be no general way to do this.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now, turning to modules, when could we find an $R$-mono from a quotient $M/∩N_i$ to the "direct sum" of $M/N_i$'s?

Comment: @karparvar The answer is basically identical, namely that there is no real point in talking about such a morphism that isn't the natural construction, and that the natural construction is fundamentally broken for the direct sum (at least, in the case where the direct sum and direct product differ).  For $\mathbb{Z}$-modules (and rings too, for that matter), think about trying to embed $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\oplus_{n\geq 1} \mathbb{Z}/n$.  Every element of the latter has $\mathbb{Z}$-torsion, a fundamental obstacle to finding a copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ in there and yet another thing that can go wrong.

Comment: I have a hunch: "if $N_i$'s are complements in $M$ (equivalently, each $N_i$ is essentially closed in $M$, namely, it has no proper essential extension in $M$) then there may exist an $R$-monomorphism from $M/∩N_i$ to the direct sum of $M/N_i$'s." In your example, none of $n\mathbb Z$'s are essentially closed in $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @karparvar No, this really isn't enough.  Take $R=\mathbb{C}[[X]]$, the power series ring over $\mathbb{C}$.  Its ideals are all of the form $(X^n)$ for some $n$, and so every ideal is an essential submodule of $R$, and we have $\cap_n (X^n) = (0)$.  Yet once again, we run into the problem that every quotient is finite-dimensional as a vector space, but $X$ generates an algebra that is infinite-dimensional as one.